# Flink Streaming - apply function in windows

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to flink and streaming as well. I want to apply a certain function per partition to each window of the stream (event time is used). What I have done so far is this:

```
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

val inputStream = env.readTextFile("dataset.txt")
      .map(transformStream(_))
      .assignAscendingTimestamps(_.eventTime)
      .keyBy(_.id)
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(windowSize),Time.seconds(slidingStep))

def transformStream(input: String): EventStream = {...}

case class EventStream(val eventTime: Long, val id: String, actualEvent: String)
```

What I want to do is to apply a general function to each partition per window batch, maybe apply a complex processing algorithm or something similar. I have seen the method apply in the DataStream API but I did not understand how it works. In Flink API it says it is used like that in Scala:

```
inputStream.apply { WindowFunction }
```

Can someone explain what the apply method does or how it is used? An example in Scala would be preferrable. Does the apply method do what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So basically there are two possible directions to follow based on the type of calculations you would like to do. Either use: `fold`/`reduce`/`aggregate` or more generic one, you already mentioned -`apply`. All of them apply to windows for a key.

As for the `apply` it is a very generic way for applying computations. The most basic version (in Scala) would be:

```
def apply[R: TypeInformation](function: (K, W, Iterable[T],Collector[R]) => Unit): DataStream[R]
```

where function takes 4 parameters:

- key of the window(remember you are working on keyedStream)
- window (you can extract e.g start or end of the window from it)
- the elements that were assigned to this particular window and key
- a collector to which you should emit results of your processing

One must remember though that this version have to keep every element in state until the window is emitted. A better memory performant solution would be to use a version with preAgreggator which performs some calculations before firing the function described above.

Here you can see a short snippet with the preaggregated:

```
val stream: DataStream[(String,Int)] =   ...

stream.keyBy(_._1)
      .window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(conf.sessionGap())))
      .apply((e1, e2) => (e1._1, e1._2 + e2._2),
             (key, window, in, out: Collector[(String, Long, Long, Int)]) => {
                out.collect((key, window.getStart, window.getEnd, in.map(_._2).sum))
      })
```

which counts appearences of a key in session windows.

So basically if you don't need the meta information of a window I would stick to the `fold` \ `reduce` \ `aggregate` if they are sufficient. Than consider apply with some kind of preaggregations and if that is not enough take a look at the most generic `apply`.

For more complete examples you may take a look [here](https://github.com/getindata/flink-use-case/blob/master/flink-processing/src/main/scala/com/getindata/FlinkProcessingJob.scala).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned you can apply map / flatmap / keyBy function calls to your stateful windowed data `val inputStream` in order to change the data. So if you were to create

`class DoSthWithYourStream {...}`

where you would define your methods and input data restrictions, then you can create another value :

`val inputStreamChanged = inputStream
.map( a => DoSthWithYourStream.Change2ColumnsIntoOne(a.change1st, a.change2nd), a)
.flatMap(new DoSthWithYourStream())`

[Examples extending Java Classed and applying Scala classes into the stream using map/flapmap/key etc](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/exercises/datastream_scala/state/TravelTimePrediction.scala)

If you want to use CEP then I think the best option is take advantage of [CEP pattern API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.1/apis/streaming/libs/cep.html)

`val pattern = Pattern.begin("start").where(_.getId == 42)
   .next("middle").subtype(classOf[SubEvent]).where(_.getVolume >= 10.0)
  .followedBy("end").where(_.getName == "end")`

`val patternStream = CEP.pattern(inputStream, pattern)`
   `val result: DataStream[Alert] = patternStream.select(createAlert(_))`

Comment: The thing is that I want to work on the entire partition and map / flatMap function calls apply a transformation on each element of the DataStream.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it needed a bit of Scala magic. What I have done so far is this:

```
    val test: DataStream[Long] = inputStream.apply(processPartition(_,_,_,_))

    def processPartition(key: String, window: TimeWindow,
                         batch: Iterable[EventStream],
                         out: Collector[Long]): Unit =  {..}
```

From my experiments the processPartition method applies a function on the whole batch that is "key partitioned" (the batch will contain only the element with the same key). I took the parameters of this method from the Java API. It would be useful if anyone could elaborate a bit more on the apply function and how it works.